# Why does ICU's Locale::getDefault() return "root"?

Tags: c++, locale, icu

Using the ICU library with C++ I'm doing:

```
char const *lang = Locale::getDefault().getLanguage();
```

If I write a small test program and run it on my Mac system, I get `en` for `lang`.  However, inside a larger group project I'm working on, I get `root`. Anybody have any idea why?  I did find this:

http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/resources

so my guess is that, when running under the larger system, some ICU resources aren't being found, but I don't know what resources, why they're not being found, or how to fix it.

### Additional Information

`/usr/bin/locale` returns:

```
LANG="en_US.ISO8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="C" 
LC_CTYPE="C" 
LC_MESSAGES="C" 
LC_MONETARY="C" 
LC_NUMERIC="C" 
LC_TIME="C" 
LC_ALL="C"
```

If I write a small C program:

```
char const *lang = setlocale( LC_ALL, "" ):
```

I get `en_US.ISO8859-1`.

**OS**: Mac OS X 10.6.4 (Snow Leopard)
**ICU version**: 4.3.4 (latest available via MacPorts).

A little help?  Thanks.

Comment: Time to make a debug ICU build and add a breakpoint.

Comment: Why MacPorts? Why not just build 'native'?

Comment: @bmargulies: Why MacPorts? Because it's easier and its entire purpose for existing is so everybody doesn't have to port/build everything themselves.

Answer (score 1):

root is surely an odd default locale - you don't see many native root-speakers these days.

But seriously, is it safe to assume on the larger system that someone hasn't called one of the variants of `setDefault("root")`?

What does something like `/usr/bin/locale` return on this system (if you can run that)?

ICU 4.4 now has a test program called '`icuinfo`', does it also return root as the default locale?

What OS/platform is this on, and which version of ICU?

Comment: If you read the info at the link I provided, it explains the "root" locale.  A simple grep through all the source code says that nobody has called setDefault.

Comment: Paul,
 I'm familiar with the root locale (and hope I did not put you off by my sarcastic first sentence). 
 Thanks for your reply- I'll look into this a bit more on MacPorts.

Comment: (Hmm, I thought I wrote this answer already:)
Can you run /usr/bin/locale from inside of the 'larger system'? Can you run u_init() as the larger system starts and report back which error code it gives?

Comment: I'm not sure how, but now everything in my environment has all the LC_ variables as well as LANG be "en_US.UTF-8".  The same is true when I do a system(3) calling /usr/bin/locale from inside the larger app.  Calling u_init() returns status 0 (no error).  ICU still returns "root".

Comment: I did this on snow leopard, macports' ICU 4.3.4

    #include <unicode/locid.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
    {
    char const *lang = Locale::getDefault().getLanguage();
    puts("lang=");
    puts(lang);
    return 0;
    }

Then:
    `icu-config --cxx --ldflags --cppflags --cxxflags` -o tst tst.cpp
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 `icu-config --invoke` ./tst

As you said it works OK from the command line - returns 'en'.

Can you say any more about the larger system? Can you run the test as the first line of your larger system's main()?